# Hibernate heavy edit session

Tags: hibernate

I have edit window, where user can edit entity and some other linked entities (which must be done in separate window opened from first edit window).

For example, let's say we have a Person, with attributes, and person have a link to department. Department can be assigned to user, changed to any another department, or user can just edit current linked department (in separate child window, with ok and cancel buttons). And let's assume this process can be more levels deep, he can edit some entity linked with department too.

What can i do with this? In my mind I have next options:

1. Open session, fetch needed entities from it and modify this entities, and commit this session, when first (parent, user) window is closed by "OK" buttom, or rollback all changes by "Cancel" button.

In this approach I can't understand how I can cancel the changes made in child windows? Moreover, is it right to keep long-life session? User can open edit window and go somewhere... seems bad.

2. Open session, fetch some, detach. Let the user work with detached entities. In some way load required entites, keep track what is changed, what is deleted or created. In the end create new session, merge all needed entities and commit it?

In this approach keep track of changes looks duplicate work, coz hibernate can do it OOTB (out of the box). And when user need some entities for edit, i must first look in my storage - maybe he already edit this? Exactly same what hibernate make OOTB.

I have try google this problem, but don't find anything. Any best practities for this pattern?

Thank you in advance, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: why don't you create hidden forms, and then set their value from the child window when closing.

and commit or rollback according to the parent ok or cancel.

Comment: how hidden forms change the situation?

Comment: creating hidden form in the parent window, when closing the child window, set the values of the child form into the form of the parent window through javascript or jquery.

Comment: this is question not about html or js. I have a java application, and forms change nothing here. The question is about how to manage large edit context with hibernate.